# How do I include an external .class file to use it in my Java code?

Tags: java

A basic question: I'm using the command line to compile and run my java code (`javac` and `java` commands respectively). Our professor provided us with a `.class` file we can use in our future projects. The class filename is `U.class`, and our professor told us which methods are in included in this class so we can invoke them in our own code. My question is, how can I tell Java I want to use this `.class` file in my code and how would I type it in the command line so to compile this (using `javac`)? The following is how my source code looks like so far:

```
import U; // This line marks an error.

public class DemoU
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        U u = new U();

        String[] myJavaFiles = u.system("dir");
        u.displayArray(myJavaFiles);
    }
}
```

I've placed both files, `DemoU.java` and `U.class`, in the same folder, and I try to compile everything using `javac DemoU.java`.

Comment: Add `.` to your classpath.

Comment: *"-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>"*

Comment: remove `import`, you don't need it as both classes in the same folder

Comment: Ask your professor to provide that shared library as a JAR, instead of simply a `.class` file.  Then just put that JAR in your classpath when you are building/executing. Done!.  Simply providing a class file can be tricky, coz you don't even know which package that class is supposed to be!  You need to put it in a correct directory structure if it is not in default package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `import U;`. You don't need it because both files are in the same location. That is what causing the problem.

Comment: The OP says "I've placed both files, DemoU.java and U.class, in the same folder, and I try to compile everything using javac DemoU.java." and you're suggesting that he do exactly what he already does. That doesn't seem very helpful.